# 10cent per product tax magento

Tags: magento

I would like to apply a flat 10 cent per product tax to my magento store, is there a way to set this up within the system already?

Answer (score 0):

- Create Product Tax Class (**Sales->Tax->Product Tax Classes**)
- Create Tax Rate (**Sales->Tax->Manage Tax Zones & Rates**)
- Create Tax Rule (**Sales->Tax->Manage Tax Rules**)
- While creating product, apply that **Product Tax Class** to the product.